# how to expose ingress-nginx port 80 from github codespaces

Tags: docker, nginx

I have the following output when running `kubectl get ingress`:

```
NAME          CLASS   HOSTS             ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
ingress-svc   nginx   localdev.me   192.168.49.2   80      32m
```

and under vs code in codespaces, I see about 5 port forwarded ports that I can access from a browser that have processes that look like this:

```
/usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 127.0.0.1 -host-port 49157 -container-ip 192.168.49.2 -container-port 22
```

I was wondering how I can configure the one with port 80 to some external port that I can access from the browser. Thank you.